# Feedback Stability Comparison

Tags: feedback, stability

Compare the Feedback conditions given below in terms of stability:-

1. Negative Feedback
2. Positive Feedback with LoopGain < 1
3. Positive Feedback with LoopGain = 1
4. Positive Feedback with LoopGain > 1

Also when are these conditions useful when used with Opamp? Thanks.

Comment: No first attempt from your side to answer the questions?

Comment: What do you meant by "LoopGain"? Is it gain around the loop? or closed-loop gain?

Answer (score 1):

Some slight corrections to your answer:

2.) Stable, but with a stability margin that may be critical; This applies, for example, to active filters (high-Q designs);

3.) Stable only for idealized conditions (no switch-on transients, no noise). In practice: Stability limit, used for designing oscillators (nominal case).

4.) Unstable - however, not necessarily saturation of the amplifier. If the condition (positive feedback) is fulfilled for one single frequency only: Oscillations with clipped amplitudes (practical design for oscillators with automatic control mechanism).

Answer (score -1):

Attempting to answer my question. Please correct me if I am wrong.

1. Negative Feedback : Most stable. Output does not change with noises at inputs or (output). Most used in general amplifiers
2. Positive Feedback with LoopGain <1 : Stable, but output can change with noise.
3. Positive Feedback with LoopGain =1 : Stable if no input is given i.e. Marginally stable. Used in Oscillators.
4. Positive Feedback with LoopGain >1 : Unstable. Any noise at any of the terminals will lead to saturation to one of the extremes. Not used.

Please give your "feedback" if improvements are needed. Thanks.

Comment: I believe @LvW meant for you to put this information into your question to demonstrate you had attempted to uncover some information relating to your question.

Comment: What do you meant by "LoopGain"? Is it gain around the loop? or *closed-loop gain*?

Comment: For my opinion, the term "loop gain" is well-defined and in common use. It is simply the gain of the complete feedback loop (including the correct sign at the summing node). That means for example: A classical opamp (open-loop gain Aol) with a feedback factor "beta" has a loop gain of LG=-Aol*beta.